# Language-Dependent DAO (i18n)

Tags: internationalization, dao, abap

I created DAOs for my database tables. In SAP ABAP you can have additional text-tables which contain the language-dependent texts (language-code is part of the key).
Currently I create DAO-instances right at the beginning of the program (Dependency Injection) and pass them a language-key which effectively binds the DAO to a specific language and let's the DAO read texts only from that specific lagnuage.

However later in the program I am required to get texts from another language. How do I cope with this?

- Explicitly include the language-key in the DAO's crud and find-by methods? This would require any client of the DAO to also expose the language-key it its methods and to properly pass it on to the DAOs, which smells. e.g. `method read(id, languageCode) returns <thing>`. Additionally I want domain-objects to know nothing of DAO/infrastructure-crap.
- Give the DAO itself a language-aware interface that allows me to create another instance of the DAO that is bound to a different language (factory). This requires me to explicitly access the DAO, which are otherwise hidden, smells too. e.g. `method createWithLang(langCode) returns <DAO>`
- Make the domain objects language-aware which means language-dependent methods explicitly expose the language-code. But then the domain objects already need to know all texts in all languages to return the proper one *or* they need direct access to some DAO to reload the proper text. Then, doing this lazily is an additional challenge (regarding ABAP OO).

Every advice greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I would probably add a parameter to the getter and setter methods that deal with language-dependent texts and set its default value to `SY-LANGU`. This way, `l_foo = lr_bar->get_baz_text( )` will implicitly get the text in the language the user logged on with, and `l_foo = lr_bar->get_baz_text( l_target_language )` will retrieve the text in any other language. You might want to pre-fetch the text in the current language when creating the object and use a hashed table to store the language-dependent texts.

Comment: Thank you. If my domain-object had a method get_baz_text( i_lang = sy-langu ), the domain-object would be responsible to load the text in the specified language. My current design however instantiates the object with the language-dependent text already loaded, so the object has no means to reload text in any other language. I rather would like to maintain that seperation between domain objects and data-access. Any advice?

Comment: Yes. Don't overdo it. You won't get any extra points for a beautiful technical design, as sad as that may be.

Answer (score -1):

In SAP, the selected language is part of the session. Your program could also have a globally available 'session' singleton where you store the user language choice.

Comment: yes, for the most time I just need the session-language. But in some application-context I need to work with another language, that is determined on business-partners that are being processed. Then, it is too late all my DAOs are bound to my session-language. I don't want to change that global session-instance's language, that would be playing around with globals and kills you in the long run. any advice?

Comment: The easiest thing sounds like just creating a new session dedicated to deal with what I assume is your BP related output.